# Fragment onCreateView not called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a **TabsPagerAdapter** class which extends **FragmentPagerAdapter**. I use it to populate 3 tabs. All the three views are Fragments.

This is how they are defined

```
public class DonorSearchFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }
}

public class DonorResultsFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }
}

public class CampDonorResultsFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }
}
```

These Fragments (as tabs) are instantiated from **TabsPagerAdapter** class like below

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Constants.SEARCH_TAB_POSITION, new DonorSearchFragment());
        fragments.add(Constants.DONORS_TAB_POSITION, new DonorResultsFragment());
        fragments.add(Constants.CAMP_DONORS_TAB_POSITION, new CampDonorResultsFragment());
    }
    ...
}
```

and in MainActivity, I instantiate the **TabsPagerAdapter** class which was shown above

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, DonorSearchFragment.ResultsChangedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        tabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }
        ..
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, the third tab(ie CampDonorResultsFragment) **onCreateView()** is not getting invoked even after instantiation as above. As a result, if I call any method on that Fragment, all the variables (instantiated in **onCreateView()** ) are null, and I get Null Pointer Exception.

What exactly happens here, why the **onCreateView()** is not called before any method on that Fragment is manually called. Also, why does not this happen on the Second Tab (DonorResultsFragment) above.

Comment: post `TabsPagerAdapter` completely!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View pager only keeps the current page, plus a number of previous/next pages as specified by [off-screen page limit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) which defaults to 1.

Consider redesigning your code so that it doesn't assume your fragments to be alive at all times. Instead of invoking methods on fragments, make the fragments pull out the data they need wherever it is available.

As a quick fix, you can set the page limit to a higher number like 2 but that won't fix the underlying design problems that will eventually bite you somewhere else.

Comment: You are correct, setOffscreenPageLimit() does work. However as suggested by you invoking methods on fragment from MainActivity should be avoided. In my scenario, I am still trying to figure out the same. Generally what would be the way where a fragment generates some data and passes to MainActivity which then in turn passes to other fragments.

Comment: For that you can use an event bus of sorts (e.g. Otto) to decouple data producers and consumers.